# Linux Control Network trafic Модификация трафика локальной сети

Tags: linux

Я хочу перенаправить трафик в моей сети. Как: Пользователь пытается зайти на example.com, но он будет перенаправлен на мой сервер apache. Пользователь заходит на vk.com, но он будет перенаправлен на мой сайт. Это должно работать только на моем Wi-Fi! Операционная система: Kali Linux

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста. Срочно!

Comment: google://прозрачный прокси

Comment: google://"captive portal", скорее.